# cakePHP 3.0 Action PagesController::myaction.json() could not be found, or is not accessible."

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am migrating an existing 2.5 app over to 3.0. I am getting an 404 error when using ajax. This works fine in cakePHP 2.5

url: "/cakephp3/pages/myaction.json"

I don't see any step that I might have missed.

I am sure it is a routing issue with the .json extension

routes.php

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {

    Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home']);
    $routes->connect('/hotel-training-courses', ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'trainingCourses']);
    $routes->connect('/feature-tour', ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'features']);
    $routes->connect('/contact-us', ['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'contact']);
    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

PagesController.php

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}

public function myaction(){

    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');

    $userName = $this->request->data['name'];
    $userCompany = $this->request->data['company'];
    $userEmail = $this->request->data['email'];
    $userPhone = $this->request->data['phone'];

    //send an email

}
```

The previous app was able to detect the request type and return with the same type. There was no need to set the render.

Comment: Please don't snip away half of the possibly relevant code... are there more routes? What does the rest of the action do?

Comment: no, there are no more routes. I have only one scope. The action does nothing yet, I have not copied over the code from the previous version. I did test returning serialised array to check if nothing is turned by action it defaults to 404. But no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Global extensions must be defined outside of scopes

`Router::extensions()` must be placed outside of, and in case it should apply to all routes, invoked before defining any scopes and routes.

In case you want to restrict extension parsing to a specific scope, use `RouteBuilder::extensions()`, ie either

```
Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home']);
    //...
});
```

or

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home']);
    //...
});
```

See **[Cookbook > Routing > Routing File Extensions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions)**

### Request::onlyAllow() doesn't exist anymore

`Request::onlyAllow()` has been renamed to `Request::allowMethod()`, so that's the next problem that you'll encouter.

See

- **[Cookbook > 3.0 Migration Guide > Network > Request](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#request)**
- **[\Cake\Network\Request::allowMethod()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Network.Request.html#_allowMethod)**

### Enable debug mode

Also you should enable debug mode so that you receive meaningful error messages with the appropriate details, necessary to debug such problems.

Comment: Thank you, moving the `Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);` outside the scope has worked. I misunderstood the docs as the examples had it inside a scope.

Comment: Yes I had spotted the `Request::allowMethod()` as I was re-reading the docs after this post. Thanks